# Scala way find elements one after another

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I am looking for method which returns true or false given a List[String] with following logic.

- The list is said to "1 start" when A is in the List
- The list is said to "2 start" when there is String "C" after String "B"

For e.g

- [A, B, Z] this list is "1 start" but not "2 start"
- [A, B, Z, C] this list "2 start" and "1 start"

Now I want a function hasTwoStarts which will return if the list has any start followed by the any of the two. That means any of the following combinations should return true:

```
"1 start" "1 start" [A, B, Z, M, A] 
"1 start" "2 start" [A, B, Z, C, T]
"2 start" "1 start" [Z, B, C, X, A]
"2 start" "2 start" [B, X, C, M, B, C]
```

and if none of the above case then its returns false

In non functional, this can be achieved with dirty loop logic but is there a better functional way to solve this?

Also minimising the list iterations.

Comment: what you have tried so far it seem like some assignment so please show your effort.

Comment: It's not an assignment, it's a problem I faced at work. I have tried it by writing a function that finds the boundary and return the list trimmed at that location.

I call the same method again after dropping the first element from the trimmed list and call the boundary function again and if that return a non empty list it should return true else false.

Comment: What about `[P, Q, B, R, C, S, C]`? Will it be said to contain **two `"2 start(s)"`** or not?

Comment: No it has only one start. B,C should be followed by A or B,C again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This solution does a single pass over the list and stops as soon as a solution is found. It is tail recursive so it should compile into a simple loop.

```
def hasTwoStarts[T](list: List[T]) = {
  @annotation.tailrec
  def loop(l: List[T], startCount: Int, seenB: Boolean): Boolean = l match {
    case _ if startCount == 2 => true
    case Nil => false
    case h :: t => h match {
      case A =>
        loop(t, startCount + 1, seenB)
      case B =>
        loop(t, startCount, true)
      case C if seenB =>
        loop(t, startCount + 1, false)
      case _ =>
        loop(t, startCount, seenB)
    }
  }

  loop(list, 0, false)
}
```

This is a very specific solution to the problem and would need to be re-worked if either of the "start" conditions were changed.

Comment: @GlobalWarrior One problem with `foldLeft` is that you can't terminate as soon as a match is found. I also find that `foldLeft` tends to look complicated and cryptic for something as complicated as this. Once you get comfortable with recursive functions they are often a better solution than `foldLeft`.

Answer (score 1):

While the question appears to be a little vague (at least come up with better names than `"1 start"` & `"2 start"`?), you can use following *code-snippet(s)*

---

Starting with these utility methods

```
// Utility methods
def endIndexOf1Start(list: List[String], startIndex: Int = 0): Option[Int] = {
  val firstIndex: Int = list.indexOf("A", from=startIndex)
  if (firstIndex >= 0) Some(firstIndex) else None
}

def endIndexOf2Start(list: List[String], startIndex: Int = 0): Option[Int] = {
  lazy val indexOfB: Int = list.indexOf("B", from=startIndex)
  lazy val indexOfC: Int = list.indexOf("C", from=indexOfB)
  if ((indexOfB >= 0) && (indexOfC > indexOfB)) Some(indexOfC) else None
}

def endIndexOfSomeStart(list: List[String], startIndexOpt: Option[Int] = None): Option[Int] = {
  val startIndex: Int = startIndexOpt.getOrElse(0)
  lazy val _endIndexOf1Start: Option[Int] = endIndexOf1Start(list, startIndex)
  lazy val _endIndexOf2Start: Option[Int] = endIndexOf2Start(list, startIndex)
  _endIndexOf1Start.orElse(_endIndexOf2Start)
}
```

---

Write a method that gives `Boolean`: whether there are 2 separate (**non-overlapping**) *starts* or not

```
// Final decider method
def containsTwoStarts(list: List[String]): Boolean = {
  lazy val endIndexOfFirstStart: Option[Int] = endIndexOfSomeStart(list)
  lazy val endIndexOfSecondStart: Option[Int] = endIndexOfSomeStart(list, endIndexOfFirstStart)
  (endIndexOfFirstStart.nonEmpty && endIndexOfSecondStart.nonEmpty)
}
```

---

Given sample input

```
// Sample input
val sampleInputs: List[List[String]] = List(
  List("A", "B", "Z", "M", "A"),
  List("A", "B", "Z", "C", "T"),
  List("Z", "B", "C", "X", "A"),
  List("B", "X", "C", "M", "B", "C")
)
```

---

Here's the input-output example

```
// invocation
sampleInputs.map(l => endIndexOf1Start(l, 0))
sampleInputs.map(l => endIndexOf2Start(l, 0))
sampleInputs.map(l => endIndexOfSomeStart(l, None))
sampleInputs.map(containsTwoStarts)
```

> ```
> res0: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(0), Some(0), Some(4), None)
> res1: List[Option[Int]] = List(None, Some(3), Some(2), Some(2))
> res2: List[Option[Int]] = List(Some(0), Some(0), Some(4), Some(2))
> res3: List[Boolean] = List(true, true, true, true)
> ```